# Check if an element with a specific class is within the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to show a `span` element, if a `div` element with a specific `class` is within the `body` and hide the `span`, if the `div` with the specific `class` isn't anymore within the `body`. So I tried to solve this with the `jQuery` function `has()`. It works for the first time as expected. But when I rename the specific `class` of the div to `specific-element-1` and reload it, the `span` is still visible. What am I doing wrong? Here the codepan, so you can easy change the `class` name to check it: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/VyObKM

PS: I also tried to solve this with the `jQuery` functions `after()` and `children()` in case of `has()`, but didn't work. Hope this is clear enough.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('body').has('.specific-element')) {
    $('.showme').show();
  } else {
    $('.showme').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="specific-element"></div>
  <span class="showme">Hello World!</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Check length property `if($('.specific-element').length > 0)`

Comment: `has()` returns a jQuery object, not a boolean, so you need to check the `length` property to see if any elements were matched.

Comment: Also in the jquery faq: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('body .specific-element').length) {
    $('.showme').show();
  } else {
    $('.showme').hide();
  }
});
```

Updated pen [here](https://codepen.io/kiranvj/pen/qpGmxX)

Comment: Perfect, it works. :) Is this also best-practice? Cheers

Comment: Best practice? not sure, but definitely not a bad way !

Comment: Given the number of upvotes on this answer, seems to be a good way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/587408/2181514 (it's also in the jquery faq)